# AutoSort Google sheet that includes dropdowns by Custom Order

Tags: sorting, google-apps-script, google-sheets

**I have to sort a sheet of data based on changeable values of dropdowns for each row.**

For example, I want all the waiters that are on-shift to have a **"Ready"** status from the dropdown. Those off-shift to have **"Off-shift"** status etc. Status is changed manually from the dropdown for each person, however, I need all the **"Ready"** waiters to appear on top, then all the **"Off-shift"** ones, then **"On-vacation"** ones etc. Each time a status from the dropdown is changed, the list should be *re-sorted automatically.*

As a novice I feel quite clueless on how to achieve this.. I tried to write a script based on similar cases I saw but it isn't working at all. Any clue on why and how it could be corrected?

```
SHEET_NAME = "Waiters";
SORT_DATA_RANGE = "A3:G15";

function customSort(array, arrayOrder, numColumn) {

    // This is the custom order list with the status options
    var order = [READY, ONSHIFT, OFFSHIFT, REST, VACATION];

    // transpose vertical 2d array into 1d array
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayOrder.length; i++) {
      order.push(arrayOrder[i][0]);    
    }

    // sort
    return array.sort(function (a, b) {
        return order.indexOf(a[numColumn-1]) - order.indexOf(b[numColumn-1]);
    });
}

function onEdit(e){
  multiSortColumns();
}
function multiSortColumns(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
  var range = sheet.getRange(SORT_DATA_RANGE);
  range.sort(customSort);
  ss.toast('Sort complete.');
}
}
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function onEdit(e){
  multiSortColumns();
}
function multiSortColumns(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
  var range = sheet.getRange(SORT_DATA_RANGE);
  var values = range.getValues();
  var order = ['READY', 'ONSHIFT', 'OFFSHIFT', 'REST', 'VACATION'];
  values.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (a[0] === '' && b[0] !== '') { return 1; }
    else if (a[0] !== '' && b[0] === '') { return -1; }
    else { return order.indexOf(a[0]) - order.indexOf(b[0]); }
  });
  range.setValues(values);
  ss.toast('Sort complete.');
}
```

Comment: Thank you lots for the reply! I tried this but it returns that READY is undefined. So I tried to make them strings - so it became var order = ["READY", "ONSHIFT", "OFFSHIFT"...]. That way it doesn't return any errors, however it also doesn't work. Any advice?

Comment: Updated. I forgot to quote your string. Also I have made the blank cell to be sorted to the bottom.

Comment: I have one more question regarding this though.. this code, for some reason only works if I only use the range of the status column - it sorts the column correctly but only that column (not the rows). However, if I try to use the whole data table which I need, it doesn't work anymore. 
I slightly changed the script above to work and now it is this:

Comment: Sorry, I cannot get what you mean. Could you add a screenshot to your question?